# Is there a way to backup one's Facebook Page to protect it from hacking?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I know it's a stretch but a family member is being paranoid about her Facebook Page being hacked and deleted. She's partially right because she was the target of a hack recently so now she looks for a way to "back up" the page.

Is there a way to back up (then restore) a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can download your Facebook account or Page data, But the functionality to restore your Facebook from downloaded information is not available.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/466076673571942?helpref=faq_content):

> If you're an admin, you can download a copy of your Page. The file includes:
>
> - Posts, photos and videos shared on the Page by people who work on the Page.
> - A list of people who have roles on the Page.
> - A description of the Page's current settings.
> - Page info from the About section.
>
> To download a copy of your Page:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. From **General**, click **Download Page**.
> 3. Click **Download Page**.
> 4. Click Create File.
>
> When the file is ready, you'll receive an email or a notification, depending on your privacy settings. From the email or notification, click **Download Page** and enter your password to continue. Keep in mind that the link to your file will expire after 4 days.